# Can I delete text messages with one swipe like mail messages on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I would like to be able to swipe completely to left and get my text messages deleted similarly to email messages.
I can swipe left and the "delete" option appears, but it's another click.
Is this possible?
Thanks

Comment: That feature is gone in iOS 7 itself.. In iOS 8 you can't do that... http://www.wikihow.com/Delete-Text-Messages-From-an-iPhone

Comment: Thanks, thought as much. Pity though.

Answer (score 1):

Currently on the iOS 8 app, this is not an available feature.